# How to extract motor from BMW 318 TDS E36 Fuel prepump to clean it

Tags: bmw, fuel-tank

It seems that a clogged motor can make it seem as the prepump (on the pic below) is dead. I noticed that a very small cleanup (external) revived it for a few minutes.

Now I would like to take the motor apart for complete inside cleanup.

I would just need advice on how to actually separate the motor from the enclosure. There are black silicone / rubber mounts around and I can't manage to remove them. I fear I could tear them.

EDIT : I confirm the motor is sealed (cf pics)

I just can't understand how I could actually take the motor out! The tube that goes to it (black) is pressed so tight against the little plastic outlet that it's nearly impossible to take out !

Also I had a bad surprise, the little filter has kind of oxidized and parts of it are going away in little pieces. I fear they could get into the injectors !

Last but not least : I managed to connect the motor itself to a 12V power source. I hear it buzzing !!!!

So I don't understand why it does not work when it is installed inside the car (the relay is ok, the fuses to !).[image]

EDIT 2 : after taking the pump system out, I connected a car battery charger to it (directly). It's also 12V so there was not so much risk of damaging it. The good news ? The pump seems to work perfectly ! I even inverted the voltage and made it a bit turn the "wrong" side, for a few seconds.

So then I just reassembled all the parts and now the car DOES use the pump, after each time I turn it on. So maybe the pump problem was due to a bad electric contact ?

Anyway. So now I also know how to unmount the motor & 2 black silicon dampers from the support. Just had to push them gently but steadily aside thanks to a flat screwdriver.

But I must say that now, I near bubble noise when I turn the pump on (just before turning the engine on). That gives an aquatic atmosphere to my car.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If this is like most intank fuel pumps, you will not be able to do as you are suggesting. These are sealed units which you cannot perform maintenance on. You can replace the pump itself from the carrier, but when the pump itself dies, you can only replace it. It would destroy it to take it apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how the pump comes out of the holder, but if you are saying the black tube is the only thing which is really holding it in, just cut it. You'll get a new hose with your new pump. The pump I just looked at had it in the parts kit. Comes with two hose clamps which connect both ends for you. You'll also get a new strainer for the bottom, so you don't have to worry about that either. Here is a picture from rockauto of one example:

[image: Airtex Fuel Pump from RockAuto.com]

Comment: Damnit, you are a KING !!! Thank you so much for these details.

Comment: Oh and just a question : why does all that system need 2 tubes going to it ? There is a thinner one, and a wider one...

Comment: @SkippyFastol ... I'm not sure, but would assume it is a fuel return for the system.

Comment: I don't understand how the system could be put under pressure if there is a fuel return...